# AC dimmer / ESP32-Wroom32d

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, ac, esp32, dimmer

I am making Leading Edge AC dimmer with ESP32-Wroom32d. I have problem with esp timer intterupts.
So I want to create a delay after zero-crossing(z.c.) (7ms) and then turn on Ac Pump and leave it on untill next z.c..
My problem is that timer interupt generates nonuniform pulses visible in the attachments (screenshot from osiloscope.)
What am I doing wrong?

```
/*  
 *  timer_frequency = clock_frequency / prescaler
 *  timer_duration = 7ms
 *  B = timer_frequency * timer_duration
 *  B = (80MHz / 16) * 7ms
 *  B = 35000
 *   
 *   
*/
volatile int B = 0;
hw_timer_t * timer = NULL;
int pumpa = 26;

void IRAM_ATTR skozi_nic() {
  digitalWrite(pumpa, LOW);
  timerAlarmWrite(timer, B, true);
  timerAlarmEnable(timer);
}

void IRAM_ATTR tim0_poln() {
  timerAlarmDisable(timer);
  digitalWrite(pumpa, HIGH);
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(pumpa, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);

  timer = timerBegin(0, 16, true); // timer 0, prescaler 16, count up
  timerAttachInterrupt(timer, &tim0_poln, true);
  //timerAlarmWrite(timer, 240, true);

  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(17), skozi_nic, RISING);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Dimmer zatemnitev");
  B = 35000; // 5000
}
```

reupload of code that works

```
/*  
 *  timer_frequency = clock_frequency / prescaler
 *  timer_duration = 7ms
 *  B = timer_frequency * timer_duration
 *  B = (80MHz / 16) * 7ms
 *  B = 35000
 *   
 *   
*/
volatile int B = 0;
hw_timer_t * timer = NULL;
int pumpa = 26;

void IRAM_ATTR skozi_nic() {
  digitalWrite(pumpa, LOW);
  timerWrite(timer, 0);
  timerAlarmWrite(timer, B, true);
  
  timerAlarmEnable(timer);
}

void IRAM_ATTR tim0_poln() {
  timerAlarmDisable(timer);
  digitalWrite(pumpa, HIGH);
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(pumpa, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(25, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  timer = timerBegin(0, 80, true); // timer 0, prescaler 16, count up
  timerAttachInterrupt(timer, &tim0_poln, true);
  //timerAlarmWrite(timer, 240, true);

  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(18), skozi_nic, RISING);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Dimmer zatemnitev");
  B = 5500; // 5000
 // digitalWrite(25, 1);
}
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried leaving out the Serial.println and see what happens? Serial doesn't play nice with strict timing.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I did try leaving out the Serial.println command, but unfortunately, it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: another suggestion: add 'timerWrite(timer, 0);' before re-enabling the alarm

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. That seemed to do the job.

Comment: thanks, I'll make an answer out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be that the timer is not reset when the alarm is re-enabled. To force this to happen, add `timerWrite(timer, 0);` before re-enabling the alarm.